# JetBrains TeamCity: Agent Executor Mode

Tags: teamcity, jetbrains-ide, agent

I setup an agent to connect to our server. Starting the agent with `./bin/agent.sh run` respectively `./bin/agent.sh start` and `./bin/agent.sh stop` works fine; everything as expected.

However, I also saw the option to start the agent in executor mode:

```
./bin/agent.sh executor BUILD_FILE [BUILD_STEP] - to run a single build or build step and exit after that (executor mode)
```

I'm interested if this is a viable alternative to running the agent in daemon mode and how one would go about to start the agent like this. I imagined that the `BUILD_FILE` is passed from the server to the agent, or that it can be fetched from the server somehow. However I could not find out where this `BUILD_FILE` is accessible on the agent or on the server.

How do I setup TeamCity so that agents run in executor mode?

Can this even be done?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like it's not yet a stable feature, or it's not intended for public use given that there still are some open tickets on YouTrack regarding it's support:

- [TW-78134](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-78134/Add-new-operation-mode-to-execute-all-the-build-stages-before-the-build-itself) Add new operation mode to execute all the build stages before the build itself
- [TW-82505](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-82505/Proper-plugin-support-for-exec-mode-of-TeamCity-agent) Proper plugin support for exec mode of TeamCity agent

If you want to spin up the agents dynamically according to the current load level, you might want to look into [TeamCity integration with cloud solutions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/teamcity-integration-with-cloud-solutions.html):

> TeamCity integration with cloud (IaaS) solutions allows TeamCity to provide virtual machines running TeamCity agents on-demand. This allows TeamCity to automatically scale the number of active build agents depending on the current workload.
>
> ...
>
> The following Cloud solutions are supported out of the box (see their dedicated articles for more details):
>
> - Amazon EC2
> - VMWare vSphere
> - Kubernetes
>
> Available as non-bundled plugins:
>
> - Windows Azure
> - Google Cloud
> - Others

I also saw your question on Jetbrains support page and if it's still unanswered there, I'm afraid there will be no other answers here either.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander thats what I feared. If I get a reply on the jetbrains forum I'll post it here.